# Spark - Reduce the no of partitions to the no of folders read

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, partition

Using spark streaming(every 5 minutes) I am storing data as parquet in HDFS.

/data/yyyy-MM-dd/*.parquet

For instance : /data/2020-02-02/*parquet

Each parquet files size is in KB's only

Each folder may contain upto 288 parquet files (max).

We usually read data for last 24 hours, Last 7 days, Last one month and so on.

When reading the data using spark and I have checked the no of partitions. Let say I am checking for last one month data and I have 288 files in each folder and it is creating 288 partitions.

When I try to repartition the data to 30 it is reducing to only 180.

Is there any way I can create one partition for one folder.

For example : When I read data for last 30 days. Is there any way I can read the data with 30 partitions. If 7 days 7 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to use the `partitionBy` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.range(1,100).withColumn("myPartition", col("id")%10)
// saving with one file per partition
df.repartition(1, $"myPartition")
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .partitionBy("myPartition")
  .parquet("output/data")
```

this should create

```
# hadoop fs -ls output/data
output/data/myPartition=0
output/data/myPartition=1
...
output/data/myPartition=9
```

with one parquet file each.

Comment: @meniluca...While writing data I am using coalesce(1). But every 5 minutes i am writing data and I am using spark append mode to do that. so I am getting new file created every 5 mins

Comment: You must first have a partition value written in the folder name like the example above. In your case should be ``/data/date=2020-02-02/*parquet``, then you must use the repartition command like in my example above ``df.repartition(1, $"date")``, this will give you the desired result, one partition per each day. Please correct your feedback.

Comment: Not for writing.. I have the folder structure as mentioned in the question. Is there any way I can read with 30 partition. Also I have not downvoted your answer

Comment: OK, got it. HDFS Files are immutable. Unfortunately there is no append to the same file, you must implement your own logic to read the folder and repartition every time you need to write in order to have 1 file per day. The best way would be to compace files after you have finished writing at the end of the day. Alas, this is a common issue. You could +1 I'd appreciate that :)